# C# - Where is Lock Appropriate to Use in Libraries?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I'm writing a library for multiple projects. And it contains classes that contain and manipulate data. So I thought I should **lock** this data while a method of those classes is executed. But I also thought if thread safe data manipulation must be done, then let the higher application layer handle locking. What would be the best practice for a **library** of classes to be used by actual applications later.

Let's say I have a class `SpecialList`. What do I do:

- lock data when methods are called
- let the user lock the list if he needs thread safety + ignore (index) exceptions so the user must catch them

?

If I knew how the .NET Framework class `List` handles that I would do the same.

---

The classes are not explicitly targeted at single- or multi-threading. They are just helping classes for all kinds of uses.

Comment: Unless your list has features specifically targeted at multithreaded scenarios it does not make any sense to have all users pay for locks they will probably never need. `List<T>` itself is not thread safe (there is a "Thread Safety" section in the documentation that explains).

Comment: No there are not targeted at multithreading. Does that mean I on low level I should avoid locks ?

Comment: Yes, you should avoid using locks. Instead simply document the thread *un*-safety.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're designing data structures and types that needs to have a guarantee about thread safety, then sure, put locks and other constructs into those types to uphold those guarantees.

However, locks alone isn't enough.

Take a simple dictionary. Let's say you want to ensure the internal data structure inside the dictionary cannot be corrupted by multiple threads, so you introduce locks. However, if the outside code does this:

```
if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    dict.Add(key, value);
```

Then there is no guarantee here that between the call to `ContainsKey` and `Add`, some other thread hasn't already added that key to the dictionary.

As such, thread-safe types may entail more things than simple locks. A method that can safely add the key and value to the dictionary if it's not already there, in an atomic operation, and then return a flag telling you what it did, may be needed.

In fact, look here: [ConcurrentDictionary.TryAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267291.aspx).

My advice would be this:

1. If you need those guarantees, design the type to be thread-safe by going through the scenarios that needs to be safe, and predictable, and implement those specifically
2. If you don't need those guarantees, don't bother doing anything, instead simply document that the type is not thread-safe, leave that to the code that uses it

The .NET type `List` does not use locks in any way, except for a few select places where thread safety is a concern, specifically the [SyncRoot property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Additionally, writing *good* thread-safe data types isn't easy. Just throwing in locks everywhere you need them will *probably* make it more thread-safe, but you will pay a hefty penalty in terms of performance. If a program doesn't need it to be thread-safe when it uses it, you still pay a lot of that price.

Writing performant thread-safe types is harder, and does usually not rely on locks (alone), but instead uses things like spin-waits, specific CPU instructions (some of which are available to .NET code), etc. But this needs highly specialized knowledge about how modern CPU's execute code.

If I were you I would leave thread-safety to the experts, and drop it from your own types, unless you absolutely need it.

Comment: I don't see how locking is not enough for thread safety. Can you give me some keywords of what to add to locking so I can read some more about it ?

Comment: Thread safety != no data corruption. A thread safe type implements the scenarios that must be thread-safe. As I said, check out the TryAdd method on ConcurrentDictionary, you can google for that as well, "concurrentdictionary tryadd" and read some of the articles.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is dependent on whether you **want** your library to be thread-safe or not. It seems trivial, but that's how it's done. Consider for example .NET's collections:

[SynchronizedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265.aspx)

[List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) (and other basic collections - not thread safe)

So a good choice seems to be doing both versions, or not thread-safe version only.